# my button click listener is not working, and no errors occurs

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

here is my code, there is no errors, tho it's not working, does anyone have any ideas why? I'm just trying to go from one activity to another by clicking on the button. i've checked the button's id in the xml file and it's true.

```
 package com.example.finalprofile;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Button b1;
   TextView text;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       try {
           this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
       b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);
       b1.setOnClickListener(moveTo());

   }

   public View.OnClickListener moveTo(){
       return new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , new_post.class);
               MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
           }
       };

   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem but make sure that `new_post activity` is registered in Manifest file

something like that.

`<activity android:name=".new_post"/`>

to successfully navigate to `new_post activity` .